# Batch script - checking and killing process

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want write batch script:

1. Open cmd.exe and then run command which run minimalized Matlab (MATLAB.exe) and then matlab app (MATLABWindow.exe)
2. After that it must check if Matlab app is working
3. if yes, do nothing (still checking)
4. if not, it will kill minimalized MATLAB.exe

What I wrote but didnt work except running matlab and matlab app:

```
@ECHO OFF
START cmd.exe /min /k "matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -minimize -r "matlab.apputil.run('ThorlabsLC100APP')""
taskkill /F /IM cmd.exe

SLEEP 30

:search
TASKLIST|FIND "MATLABWindow.exe"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 (
GOTO search)
ELSE (GOTO found)
TIMEOUT /T 5
GOTO search

:found
taskkill /im MATLAB.exe

EXIT
```

Thanks

Comment: If you found a solution, please do not include it in your question, but post it as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
if not DEFINED IS_MINIMIZED set IS_MINIMIZED=1 && start "" /min "%~dpnx0"  %* && exit
@ECHO OFF
START /min cmd.exe /k "matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -minimize -r "matlab.apputil.run('ThorlabsLC100APP')""


timeout /t 30 /nobreak


:loop
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq MATLABWindow.exe" | findstr "MATLABWindow.exe" >nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto mycode
goto loop

:mycode

taskkill /F /IM MATLAB.exe
taskkill /F /IM cmd.exe

end
```